# tool tip with content

Tags: css, html, tooltip

[image]

How to create a static tooltip like above. Pls help would be great

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do it, some with CSS only and some using JavaScript.

Here is a [CSS only solution](http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/css-tooltip):

```
<!--First tooltip-->
<a href="#" class="tooltip">
    Tooltip
    <span>
        <img class="callout" src="cssttp/callout.gif" />
        <strong>Most Light-weight Tooltip</strong><br />
        This is the easy-to-use Tooltip driven purely by CSS.
    </span>
</a>

a.tooltip {outline:none; }
a.tooltip strong {line-height:30px;}
a.tooltip:hover {text-decoration:none;} 
a.tooltip span {
    z-index:10;display:none; padding:14px 20px;
    margin-top:-30px; margin-left:28px;
    width:300px; line-height:16px;
}
a.tooltip:hover span{
    display:inline; position:absolute; color:#111;
    border:1px solid #DCA; background:#fffAF0;}
.callout {z-index:20;position:absolute;top:30px;border:0;left:-12px;}

/*CSS3 extras*/
a.tooltip span
{
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 8px #CCC;
}
```